# how to highlight a particular data point in MP android Line chart?

Tags: android, highlight, mpandroidchart

I am having a list view with data points in it. Now, what I want is to highlight the data point on the graph when I clicked on a particular data point in the List view. I want to increase the size of the data point circle and change its color.

```
  mChart.removeAllViews();
    mChart.setOnChartGestureListener(this);
    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    setData();
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
    mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
    mChart.setDragEnabled(false);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
    mChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(true);

    final XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setLabelRotationAngle(270);
    xAxis.setAxisLineWidth(3);
    xAxis.setTextSize(12f);
    xAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
  //  xAxis.setGranularity(0f);
    xAxis.setLabelCount(xAxisStringValues.length,true);

    xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                if (value > 0 || value < readingDateGlucose.length)
                {
                        return xAxisStringValues[(int) value];
                }
            return "-";
        }

        @Override
        public int getDecimalDigits() {
            return 0;
        }
    });

    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.removeAllLimitLines();
    leftAxis.setAxisLineWidth(3);
    leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
    leftAxis.setTextSize(12f);
    leftAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
            return "" + ((int) value);
        }

        @Override
        public int getDecimalDigits() {
            return 0;
        }
    });
    leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    leftAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);
    leftAxis.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.setAutoScaleMinMaxEnabled(true);
    mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.animateX(2500, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuart);

    mChart.invalidate();
```

This is how, I am drawing my chart.And, I have used MP Android v3.0.0 library. I have seen this link already, but not able to understand from it:[circular highlighted data points](https://github.com/WW-Digital/MPAndroidChart/pull/9/commits/0e30e21aac868399628160eb689ede11a02ae9da)

this is how I have implemented my on click listner `final AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {
                listPosition = position;
            }
        };`

And this is how I am creating my data set ` set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "");

```
    set1.setFillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    set1.setColor(Color.RED);
    set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLUE);
    set1.setLineWidth(2f);
    set1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    set1.setValueTextSize(10f);
    set1.setCircleRadius(2f);
    set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
    set1.setHighlightEnabled(true);
    set1.setDrawValues(false);
    set1.setDrawFilled(true);
    ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1);
    LineData data = new LineData(dataSets);
    mChart.setData(data);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Design an icon which you want to display instead of circle. Place that icon in drawable folder of you project. Get your specific value on which you want to display your icon as:

```
set1.getEntryForIndex(index).setIcon(getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
```

After that replace index with your entry index for example for first entry use 0. Also replace icon with your icon name in drawables.

Comment: set1.getEntryForIndex method does not contain any method setIcon . It is showing cannot resolve method setIcon().

Comment: I tested that and it works buddy. Which version you are using?

Comment: I used version 3.0.2. I think you are using 2.1.6 so let me check for that if I can do that I will share the solution in a while.

Comment: Buddy I am unable to find setIcon method in v 2.1.6. I recommend you to use latest version of mpCharts and I can share working example for that. Its not much of work but you can achieve by that what you are looking for.

Comment: Okay try implementing using version 3.0.2 then apply that setIcon method. If you need further assistance then do contact me buddy. I will help you. Code for everyone !